# UILabel text alignment to centre in collectionView iOS 6 for multiple lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uicollectionview, ios6.1

I'm using a `UILabel` in collection view cell which is centre aligned and has multiple lines. I'm using `adjustFontSizeToFitWidth = YES` and `minimumFontScale = 0.5` to reduce the font size when text does not fit. This works fine in iOS 7.

But in iOS 6 the text alignment goes to the left. To align it to centre I used `adjustLetterSpacingToFitWidth = NO` which I found in other threads, this aligns the text to centre but the text doesn't fit and leaves a "..." trail in the end.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `UITextView` which will allow you to wrap the text, unlike the `UILabel`. If you want all of your text on one line you could make it so that in iOS 7 the text is shrunk one amount and in iOS 6 it is shrunk more.

Comment: the shrunking text part did not work in iOS 6.1 and like I said in ios7 it works fine so i wouldn't want to switch to textview now. Could this be some sort of bug in ios6 itself that it doesn't work?

Comment: You could always make it so the minimum iOS required is iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Now UILabel has [textLabel sizeToFit]; for label size changing also you can use following code:

textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

[textLabel sizeToFit];

Comment: you should use the code syntax to format your post !